# Laravel validate data coming from my own application and database

Tags: php, laravel

In a function in my **controller** I call this:

```
$item = Item::where('i_id', $Id)->where('type', 1)->first();


$firebaseData = app('firebase')->getDatabase()->getReference('items/'.$Id)->getSnapshot()->getValue();
```

Then I do a lot of "validation" between the data from the two sources above like:

```
if ($item->time_expires < strtotime(Carbon::now()) && $firebaseData['active'] == 1) { 
return response()->json(['errors' => [trans('api.pleaserenew')]], 422); 
}
```

And since this is not data coming from a user/request I cant use Laravels `validate` method

I dont want to keep this kind of logic inside my controller but where should I put it? Since part of my data is coming from Firebase I cant setup a Eloquent model to handle it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any data you have in your application you can use Laravel validation.

You can merge your data and process it using Validator facade like this:

```
$combinedData = array_merge($item->toArray(), $firebaseData);

Validator::make($combinedData, [
    'active' => 'required|in:1',
    'time_expires' => 'required|before:' . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
], $customMessageArray);
```

I think the best place for this code is some kind of service class you will inject to controller or other service class using Laravel dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to receive the firebase data via a method within the model:

```
public function getFirebaseData()
{
    app('firebase')->getDatabase()->getReference('items'/ . $this->i_id)->getSnapshot()->getValue();
}
```

That way you have the logic to receive the data decoupled from controller logic and moved it to where it makes more sense. Adding a validation method could work similarily within the model then:

```
public function validateData()
{
    $combined = array_merge($this->toArray(), $this->getFirebaseData());

    Validator::make($combined, [
        'active' => 'in:1',
        'time_expires' => 'before:' . Carbon::now(),
    ]);
}
```

The caveat with this is that the validation error will be thrown within the model instead of the controller, but that shouldn't really be an issue I don't think.